# Why can't I create a file mapping with a text file?

Tags: c++, file

I'm using the following code from Microsoft as a template:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");
TCHAR szMsg[]=TEXT("Message from first process.");

int _tmain()
{
   HANDLE hMapFile;
   LPCTSTR pBuf;

   hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
                 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
                 NULL,                    // default security
                 PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
                 0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
                 BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
                 szName);                 // name of mapping object

   if (hMapFile == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());
      return 1;
   }
   pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,   // handle to map object
                        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
                        0,
                        0,
                        BUF_SIZE);

   if (pBuf == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());

       CloseHandle(hMapFile);

      return 1;
   }


   CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, szMsg, (_tcslen(szMsg) * sizeof(TCHAR)));
    _getch();

   UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

   CloseHandle(hMapFile);

   return 0;
}
```

And it works nicely, but I want to use a file called `file.txt` instead of the paging file, so I think these changes should be enough:

```
ficheroACompartir=CreateFile("file.txt",GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

   if (ficheroACompartir==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
       printf("Could not open file\n");
       getchar();
   }
   else
   {
       printf("File opened correctly\n");
       ReadFile(ficheroACompartir,buff,4096,&dwBytesRead,NULL);
       printf("%s\n",&buff); //double check that the file is opened correctly in case I'm forgetting something, content displays fine

       //CloseHandle(ficheroACompartir);
   }

   hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
                 ficheroACompartir,    // use my file
                 NULL,                    // default security
                 PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
                 0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
                 BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
                 szName);                 // name of mapping object
```

But those changes do not work, I get a "could not create file mapping object" error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are calling `CreateFile` to open the text file, you state that you only want read access to it (`GENERIC_READ`), so the returned file handle only has read-only access to the file.  When you then create the file mapping to it, you state that you want read/write access.  Since the file handle has read-only access, this is not possible and the file mapping fails.

Change the second parameter of your `CreateFile` to `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` instead.

Comment: Also, this is clearly stated in the [`CreateFileMapping()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537.aspx) documentation: "*PAGE_READWRITE 0x04: Allows views to be mapped for read-only, copy-on-write, or read/write access. **The file handle that the hFile parameter specifies must be created with the GENERIC_READ and GENERIC_WRITE access rights**.*" When `CreateFileMapping()` failed, `GetLastError()` should have told you that you had a mismatch in access rights. ALWAYS check error codes when they are available!